# Spring boot with spring security: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm building a web application for learning purpose. But when tried to implement spring security, and running the application, I'm getting **Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration'**. After completing schema export, this error is showing in console.

I have attached my **build.gradle** file, **application.properties** file, spring security configuration class and of course error logs too.

Tried through searching on this site too. But have not found anything relevant to my one.

***build.gradle is:***

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.development'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.0.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.0.3.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.webjars.bower:bootstrap:4.0.0-beta'
    compile 'org.webjars.bower:jquery:3.3.1'
    compile 'org.webjars.npm:popper.js:1.13.0'
    compile 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:1.4.0'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'

    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

***application.properties is:***

```
# LOGGING
logging.file=onlineQuiz.log
logging.level.com.development.onlineQuiz=DEBUG

# THYMELEAF
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlinequiz
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=nopass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# JPA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

***My spring security configure class is :***

```
package com.development.onlineQuiz.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
            //  .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("user")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .loginPage("/index");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Mukit").password("pass").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

***And the error I'm getting is:***

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-24 20:37:05.923 ERROR 2060 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.development.onlineQuiz.OnlineQuizApplication.main(OnlineQuizApplication.java:10) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.configureContentNegotiation(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:59) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.configureContentNegotiation(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:62) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcContentNegotiationManager(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:375) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcContentNegotiationManager(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:465) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dc037ac.CGLIB$mvcContentNegotiationManager$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dc037ac$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$62192ff4.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dc037ac.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5 is build around Spring Security 4.x however in your list of dependencies you have Spring Security 5 as a dependency. As you are using Spring Boot it is recommended to use the starters provided by Spring Boot, that way you get the version belonging to that version of Spring Boot. So instead of adding dependencies on `org.springframework.security` projects use `spring-boot-starter-security` instead.

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

Comment: what if you want to use oauth2, which is not in spring security 4.x but it is in spring security 5.x?